# Why is assigning many variables seem to mutate my variable?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I'm new to Smalltalk so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but this seems very weird and buggy.

```
dict := Dictionary new.
dict at: 1 put: 1.
dict at: 2 put: 2.
dict at: 3 put: 3.
dict at: 4 put: 4.


1 to: 4 do: [:j |

  key := j.

  value := dict at: key.
  value print.

  value printNl.
].
```

This code works fine and correctly print

```
11
22
33
44
```

But then, if I add enough assignments to other variables the result of the script change:

```
dict := Dictionary new.
dict at: 1 put: 1.
dict at: 2 put: 2.
dict at: 3 put: 3.
dict at: 4 put: 4.


1 to: 4 do: [:j |

  key := j.

  value := dict at: key.
  value print.


  unrelated := 1.
  unrelated2 := 1.
  unrelated3 := 1.
  unrelated4 := 1.
  unrelated5 := 1.
  unrelated6 := 1.
  unrelated7 := 1.
  unrelated8 := 1.
  unrelated9 := 1.
  unrelated10 := 1.

  value printNl.

].
```

This code now prints

```
11
21
31
41
```

If I remove the line assigning `unrelated10` it works again... Am I missing something or is GNU Smalltalk buggy ?

I am using GNU Smalltalk version 3.2.5.

Comment: How are the `unrelated` variables defined? I mean, are they ivars, temporaries, shared?

Comment: As I said, I'm pretty new to Smalltalk so I don't have a clear idea of what this means. In both case, my code is the full script that I'm running directly with gst : `gst myfile.st`. So there is no extra code besides what I posted.

Comment: I'm not a GNU Smalltalk user but you are doing nothing wrong. There must be a problem with the max number of temporaries (automatically defined?) in a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is a bug in GNU Smalltalk. It appears that the system allows you to reference variables that have not been defined (this "feature" is not standard) and the system's attempt to define the variables and their scope is having problems.

The work-around is to define your own variables and give them as narrow a scope as possible (this is good practice in any language). So, try the following (validated at [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smalltalk_online.php)):

```
| dict |
dict := Dictionary new.
dict at: 1 put: 1.
dict at: 2 put: 2.
dict at: 3 put: 3.
dict at: 4 put: 4.


1 to: 4 do: [:j |
  "The following is a list of variables used in this code block"
  | key value 
    unrelated unrelated2 unrelated3 unrelated4 unrelated5
    unrelated6 unrelated7 unrelated8 unrelated9 unrelated10 |
     
  key := j.

  value := dict at: key.
  value print.

  unrelated := 1.
  unrelated2 := 1.
  unrelated3 := 1.
  unrelated4 := 1.
  unrelated5 := 1.
  unrelated6 := 1.
  unrelated7 := 1.
  unrelated8 := 1.
  unrelated9 := 1.
  unrelated10 := 1.

  value printNl.
].
```

Comment: It makes sense, it was a bit confusing to see such a bug but it makes sense if I was relying on bad practices and undefined behavior. Thanks a lot!